# Raise exception if XML element does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have multiple procedures that accept XML parameters (I know I could use a TVP instead, but it fits with an older approach where the application also passes XML).

The following code populates a table from XML:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (userID int, colA int);
DECLARE @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rows>
    <row userId="1" colA="234" />
    <row userId="1" colB="564" />
    <row userId="1" colA="252" />
</rows>';

INSERT INTO @tmp 
    (userID, colA) 
SELECT 
    u.n.value('@userId', 'int'),
    u.n.value('@colA', 'int')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/rows/row') AS u (n);

SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

Note however that the second line of XML doesn't actually have a colA element.  I know this creates a NULL in the table, but in my app, NULL values are permitted.

```
userID      colA
----------- -----------
1           234
1           NULL
1           252
```

So, is there any way to perform some type of check in TSQL (like this) before the data is populated?

```
For each XML row
    If (userId element does not exist) OR (colA element does not exist) Then
        RAISERROR (caught by BEGIN/END TRAN within procedures/calling procedure)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLXML [`exist`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) for that:

```
select @xml.exist('rows/row[not(@colA)]')
```

will return `1` if there's a row which doesn't have `colA` attribute. So you can use something like

```
if @xml.exist('rows/row[not(@colA)]') = 1
    ...
    -- raiserror here
    ...
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26558)</kbd>**

Comment: Superb, thanks.  If the above code was inside a procedure called by another procedure, would I need to ROLLBACK directly after your example, and then call RAISERROR straight after ROLLBACK, or would ROLLBACK be handled entirely by the first procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tmp WHERE userId IS NULL OR colA IS NULL)
BEGIN 
  RAISERROR ('Your Error Message', 16, 1)

END
```

Comment: Sorry that won't work (please see post where I state that NULLs are permitted).  Thanks anyway